# Using elvis operator with strings on an within Angular 5 "onSubmit"

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have the following code that is being executed as part of a "onSubmit" under Angular 5

```
(error: any) => {
  let errMsg: String;
  errMsg = "ERROR :" + !error.error.isObject(Text) ?
    "Message not returned. Be sure server is accessible."
    : error.error ; 

  console.error(errMsg);
  this.errorMsg = errMsg;
  console.error(error);  // <-- leaving this here just in case ...
  return;
});
```

Everything seems to be working OK, except the text  **"ERROR :"*** is not showing up in the response messages. Only the text themselves. So, instead of seeing:

> ERROR: Message not returned. Be sure server is accessible. ( which is
>   wanted )

I see

> Message not returned. Be sure server is accessible. (which is not
>   wanted)

How can this be fixed?

TIA

Comment: Use `"ERROR :" + ( !error.error.isObject(Text) ? "Message not returned. Be sure server is accessible." :  error.error ); `

Comment: `!test ? ifTrue() : ifFalse();` is a painful way to test something. `?` on its own is not a terrific idea but if you add negation on top of that... Man that comes pretty close to obfuscation!

Comment: That is ternary operator, not elvis.

Comment: It is NOT elvis operator, so the title itself is misleading. `?.` is Elvis. `?` is not. There's no microphone.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, Better name is _conditional operator_

Comment: @Satpal: javascript may be the only language to call it that. Most everywhere else it's known as "ternary" :)

Answer (score 1):

Your statement:

```
errMsg = "ERROR :" + !error.error.isObject(Text) ?
  "Message not returned. Be sure server is accessible."
  : error.error ;
```

is responsible for your unwanted behavior.

Everything left to `?` is considered to be the tested part. So that means `"ERROR :" + !error.error.isObject(Text)` is your condition in your case.

You need to add parenthesis to fix that:

```
errMsg = "ERROR :" + (!error.error.isObject(Text) ?
  "Message not returned. Be sure server is accessible."
  : error.error);
```

That way, nothing outside the parenthesis can be interpreted as the condition to your `?` expression.

---

By the way, please invert your condition. Also you can simplify the first two lines, and I'd leave the ternary operator behind in your case for the sake of readability (it's not always good to write shorter code). Final code could be:

```
(error: any) => {
  if (error.error.isObject(Text)) {  // <-- This is suspicious, what's the plan here?
    this.errorMsg = "ERROR :" + error.error;
  } else {
    this.errorMsg = "Message not returned. Be sure server is accessible.";
  }

  console.error(this.errorMsg);
  console.error(error);  // <-- leaving this here just in case ...
});
```

Comment: And the solution is, as always, well-placed parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

```
errMsg = "ERROR :" +  (!error.error.isObject(Text) ? "Message not returned. Be sure server is accessible." :  error.error );
```

Otherwise "ERROR :" will also be evaluated.